# How do I write access to users regarding SSH server for remote control in Linux Mint?

Tags: ssh, ip, remote, hosts, user

SSH server is on computer #1. Computer #1 is running Linux Mint. Computer #2 is running OS X. I used the following command:

```
ssh mike_10.0.0.188
```

The IP address is from ifconfig from the terminal as root.

Comment: and the question is? Can you be more clear what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I installed a SSH server on my Linux Mint OS computer. How do I use my OS X computer to connect to my first computer?

Answer (score 0):

Manual page is usually good start. `man ssh` is what you are looking for. There is synopsis:

```
ssh [...] [user@]hostname [command]
```

describing exactly what you need. If your Linux IP is `10.0.0.188` and your Linux user is `mike`, then:

```
ssh mike@10.0.0.188
```

Comment: I tried that and I got "ssh: connect to host 10.0.0.188 port 22: Connection refused"

Comment: So then `ssh` is not running on the linux host or firewall is running on that host. Still to much possibilities.